# Javascript Modal with dynamic XML Content

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML DB with movies. Each movies comes with a picture. On click on the picture modal opens and in the modal you can see the information about the movie. With the following code I am able to iterate over all my pictures, which are buttons.

```
btn.forEach(element => {
 element.addEventListener("click", () => {                              
  modal.style.display = "block";                    
 } );
} );
```

Problem is, this opens the same modal all the time, meaning, the content is not dynamically changing, depending on the movie I click. I tried the following

```
btn.forEach(element => {
 element.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.forEach(item => {
   item.style.display = "block";
  });
 });
});
```

But this changes the content to the last on the data base, showing again same modal all the time and also breaking the close span for all modals. How do I show a correct modal for each movie?

Comment: It would helpful to help, if provided a sample generated html info, and how variables `btn` and  `modal` are initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use arrow functions here because of context or so to say binding 'this' the best way is to use a plain old function and some DOM traversing

The thing is you havent supplied code for **btn** so I don't know how are you selcting all buttons but I would do it like so:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('btn')).map(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const theContainer = this.closest('.container')
  theContainer.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].classList.add('show')
  theContainer.getElementsByClassName('close')[0].onclick = function(){
    this.closest('.modal').classList.toggle('show')
  }
}))
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='modal'>
    <p> modal </p>
    <button class='close'>X</button>
  </div>
  <button class='btn'>0</button>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='modal'>
    <p> modal 1</p>
    <button class='close'>X</button>
  </div>
  <button class='btn'>1</button>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='modal'>
    <p> modal 2</p>
    <button class='close'>X</button>
  </div>
  <button class='btn'>2</button>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='modal'>
    <p> modal 3</p>
    <button class='close'>X</button>
  </div>
  <button class='btn'>3</button>
</div>
```